# Custom font in widget

Tags: android, time, fonts, android-widget

I am trying to create a simple android widget that shows The time but uses a custom font. Anyone knows how to do this? 
I've tried this:
[Problem showing time using custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377668/problem-showing-time-using-custom-font)

But it will not work. First getAssets() will not work because it needs the context and if I remove the line that sets up the custom font after a couple of seconds I will get the **failed binder transaction** error.

Anyone can help or give me a link to a tutorial?
Also is it a good practice to update the time with a timer?

My code
**LWidget.java**

```
public class LWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

//=============================================================================================
//On Update
//=============================================================================================


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
    int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager), 1, 1000);



        //views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.TimeView, buildUpdate(time));





    }
//=============================================================================================
//Timer class
//=============================================================================================

    private class MyTime extends TimerTask {
        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
        ComponentName thisWidget;
        DateFormat timeformat = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
        public MyTime(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {
        this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, LWidget.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Calendar ci = Calendar.getInstance();
        String time = timeformat.format(ci.getTime());
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview,"Time = " + time);
        remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_imageview, buildUpdate(time));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
        }
    }

//=============================================================================================
//bitmap font
//=============================================================================================
    public Bitmap buildUpdate(String time) 
{
        Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(160, 84, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        //if I remove the comment here, getAssets() will not work

        //Typeface clock = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/Crysta.ttf");
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setSubpixelText(true);
       // paint.setTypeface(clock);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextSize(65);
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        myCanvas.drawText(time, 80, 60, paint);
        return myBitmap;
 }




//=============================================================================================
//On receive
//=============================================================================================
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // v1.5 fix that doesn't call onDelete Action
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
            final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
            AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
                this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
            }
            } else {
                super.onReceive(context, intent);
            }
    }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView android:id="@+id/widget_textview"
android:text="@string/widget_text"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
android:padding="10dip"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

<ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/widget_imageview"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

**ltime_widget_provider.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="146dip"
android:minHeight="72dip"
android:updatePeriodMillis="10000"
android:initialLayout="@layout/main"
/>
```

Comment: Vincenzo try to use `getApplicationContext()` and `getBaseContext()` instead of this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use an `AlarmManager` instead of a Timer.
You can not use a Timer [because](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html):

> `AppWidgetProvider` is an extension of `BroadcastReceiver`, your
>   process is not guaranteed to keep running after the callback methods
>   return.

Use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508179/appwidget-alarmmanager-not-updating) for reference.

> getAssets() will not work because it needs the context

`onUpdate()` provides a `Context`, no?

Answer (score 0):

okay try this way :

```
static Context con;  

Typeface clock = Typeface.createFromAsset(con.getAssets(),"fonts/KacstLetter.ttf");
```

Comment: Your code lacks the assignment of `con`. With just these changes, it will result in an NPE. Besides that, there's no need to save the context in a static field, in fact it's a bad idea because the code cannot be reused in different contexts. Just go for a regular, non-static field instead. PS: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: sorry i mean " static Context con;  " put it before  
 > 
public Bitmap buildUpdate(String time) {// ... }