# Android: Custom font for XML in AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, xml, layout, fonts, android-appwidget

I am trying to use a custom font for my app, and have the XML layout use this custom font. I followed the instructions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android), but the problem is that I get the following crash:

```
W/AppWidgetHostView(  519): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
W/AppWidgetHostView(  519): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class com.example.RobotoTextView
```

Because this is running inside an AppWidgetProvider, I wonder if it is going to work. Maybe there is a work around (except going through each widget ID and changing the typeface in Java) please. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

App Widget layouts are based on `RemoteViews`, which do not support every kind of layout or view widget. They do support some Android widgets, including `TextView`. However, descendants of these classes are not supported. (Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Instead you might want to try this: [Problem showing time using custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377668/problem-showing-time-using-custom-font)